# Writing data in file

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I do a iphone apps and I try to write in a file like this:

```
data = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:LogString length:[LogString length]];
file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
[file seekToEndOfFile];
[file writeData: data];
[file closeFile];
```

But the problem is that if I try to write the string "awf", the content of the file is "†∂…‡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `LogString` correctly.  I'm assuming it's a string, since that's the logical choice for an object with a `-length` method (and that's not already an `NSData`).

If that's the case, you should do:

```
data = [LogString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
[file seekToEndOfFile];
[file writeData: data];
[file closeFile];
```

Comment: Hey this is work good, but I have a warning, "Incompatile objective-c types assigning "struct nsdata", expected struct nsmutable data. Do you think this is a problem?

Comment: @Alex you only need to declare `data` as an `NSMutableData` if you're going to change the contents afterwards.  In the code you posted, you don't need it to be mutable.